# trying to create a discord bot but whenever i run it i get an unexpected end of input this is the most recent code ive added

Tags: javascript, discord.js

trying to create a discord bot but whenever i run it i get an unexpected end of input this is the most recent code ive added

im just trying to add a reedit **scraper** to my discord bot thats it i probably imported the code wrong or something im not sure it came from http://www.netinstructions.com/simple-web-scraping-with-node-js-and-javascript/

client.on('message', msg => {
if (msg.content === 'Reddit') {

```
request("https://www.reddit.com", function(error, response, body) {
  if(error) {
    msg.reply("Error: " + error);
  
  msg.reply("Status code: " + response.statusCode);

  var $ = cheerio.load(body);

  $('div#siteTable > div.link').each(function( index ) {
    var title = $(this).find('p.title > a.title').text().trim();
    var score = $(this).find('div.score.unvoted').text().trim();
    var user = $(this).find('a.author').text().trim();
    msg.reply("Title: " + title);
    msg.reply("Score: " + score);
    msg.reply("User: " + user);
});
```

Comment: You're missing a whole bunch of closing brackets

Answer (score 0):

`Unexpected end of input` indicates an issue with the syntax. Specifically, you're missing four brackets, two parentheses and two semicolons.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'Reddit') {
    request("https://www.reddit.com", function(error, response, body) {
      if(error) {
        msg.reply("Error: " + error);
      } // missing bracket

      msg.reply("Status code: " + response.statusCode);

      var $ = cheerio.load(body);

      $('div#siteTable > div.link').each(function(index) {
        var title = $(this).find('p.title > a.title').text().trim();
        var score = $(this).find('div.score.unvoted').text().trim();
        var user = $(this).find('a.author').text().trim();
        msg.reply("Title: " + title);
        msg.reply("Score: " + score);
        msg.reply("User: " + user);
      }); // missing bracket, closing parentheses and semicolon
    }); // missing bracket, closing parentheses and semicolon
  } // missing bracket
});
```